# Setting up global array (outwith class)

Tags: php, arrays, variables, global

I have a few classes (in separate files, eg /classes/admin.class.php), and I'd like them to have access to a global array, which is loaded in the main file (index.php).

I want the contents of the global array to be `$cq->fetch_assoc()`.

How do I do this? I've read up about it, but I simply cannot get my head around it.

`$GLOBALS` seems to work, but is that not an outdated version (like `$HTTP_POST_ARRAY`?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any variable you declare in the index.php file will be available to all the subsequently included files.  However, once you go into a function definition, that variable won't be available.  You can make it available by using the "global" keyword.

For example:

index.php

```
<?php
   $var = $cq->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

/classes/admin.inc.php

```
<?php
echo $var; //Will work!

function foo() {
    global $var;

    echo $var; //Won't work without global keyword!
}
```

Comment: OK, I've done that, but I'm getting `unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_FUNCTION`. Does it matter that it's a class, rather than a function?

Comment: You can't declare a class variable to be global. `class x() { global $y; }` is not valid PHP.

Comment: So, is there any way to access the content of the variable?

Comment: I don't fully understand your setup. Could you elaborate on what your trying achieve?

Comment: I'm just went with using `$GLOBALS`, since that appears to work :)

Answer (score 0):

> `$GLOBALS` seems to work, but is that not an outdated version (like `$HTTP_POST_ARRAY`?)

No, that are two different things. `$GLOBALS` is not outdated, but *the* superglobal variable that gives you access to the global variable table in PHP.

`$HTTP_POST_ARRAY` is outdated, because you should use `$_POST` instead.